# C function that doesn't 'wait' for any input, but detects if any?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, input, codeblocks

Is there a C function that doesn't wait for input but if there is one, it detects it?
What I'm trying to do here is continue a loop endlessly until any key is pressed.
I'm a newbie, and all the input functions I've learned so far waits for the user to input something..
I hope I'm clear, although if I'm not I'm happy to post the code..

Comment: What OS & compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikeNakis Windows 7 Ultimate x86 and code::blocks with GNU GCC compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIndows kbhit( ) does exactly this **non-blocking keyboard char-ready check**, and there's a kbhit( ) for Linux [**over here**](http://pwilson.net/kbhit.html)

Comment: thank you.. kbhit() with getch() to retrieve what's been pressed works awesome.. :)

Comment: @Shashwat Mehta -- Good for you! Thanks for the feedback. Please don't forget to accept this answer if it works out for you.

Comment: Link "http://pwilson.net/kbhit.html" --> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED Oct 2021

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody's stated it clearly....

The important thing to note is that the standard library provided by C does *not* provide the capability you're looking for. Achieving it, then, requires the use of third party libraries and/or special knowledge about the operating system you're using.

Typically, you'll have some of those third-party libraries available. If you were using Visual Studio, for example, you would be able to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c(v=VS.100).aspx. I'm not sure what's available to you with your setup.

Comment: thank you.. kbhit() with getch() to retrieve what's been pressed works awesome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check signal() if all you need is a way to stop the loop and run your end of the program function.

It depends what you exactly want to do, but in general:

A) You keep your program single-threaded and check input through a non-blocking input read.

B) You spawn a different thread that will handle the input and communicate the results back to the main thread.

Comment: Well, that elusive "non-blocking input read" is precisely what he is asking for.